# Using terratest with a separate backend.hcl file

Tags: terratest

I am using terratest successfully, but since switching to a remote backend, where the details are defined in a separate `backend.hcl` file, I am running into trouble.

The situation: my `main.tf` starts like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.14.0"
  backend "remote" {}
}
```

And my `backend.hcl`:

```
workspaces { name = "foobar" }
hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
organization = "ACME"
```

Then when using terraform, I init like `terraform init -backend-config=./backend.hcl`. So far, so good. When using terratest, it now complains among other errors about the `organization` not beeing defined. This seems reasonable, as `organization` is not in `main.tf`.

One workaround would be to include the contents of `backend.hcl` in `main.tf`, but that would not fit with our architecture, it would require to edit `main.tf` just for testing.

Is there a way to tell terratest to include the `backend.hcl` when terraform initing?

EDIT 1: I see there is a way to add backend information to the `terraformOptions`, however I was not able to correctly format these:

```
BackendConfig: map[string]interface{}{
  "organization": "ACME",
  "hostname": "app.terraform.io",
  "workspaces": "{ name = "foobar" }",
},
```

If I could get this to work this would provide a workaround, as I could add some code to read the `backend.hcl` and inject the information, however the workspaces formatting is not correct and I am a bit lost as to how that should look.

EDIT 2: Ok, now I found out that my workaround mentioned in EDIT 1 will not work because workspaces is a block value, which is currently not supported. The issue is open since 2019 ... https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21830.

So it would be really helpfull if terratest would support the backend configuration in a file.